# Directed Acyclic Graph with minimized merging nodes

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization, dag

Suppose that we have a set of paths that all of them strat from the source "I" and end to the destination "O". The paths might have shared nodes. We are allowed to change the sequence of nodes on paths. Now, I would like to create a DAG such that the number of merging edges (converging paths) are minimized. The number of divergeng branches doesn't matter.

Example:
We have two sets of vertices to create a graph containing two paths:
{I,a,b,c,O} and {I,b,c,d,O}

The first solution:

**Graph1:** {I -> a -> b -> c -> O}, {I -> b -> c -> d -> O}
Here we will have 2 merging nodes at nodes b and O with 4 merging edges

The second solution:

**Graph2:** {I -> a -> b -> c -> O}, {I -> d -> b -> c -> O}
Here we only have changed the sequence of nodes in the second path and consequently we will have 1 merging node with 2 merging edges which is fewer than Graph1.

Is there any algorithm or optimization methods to formulate the problem of finding a DAG with minimized merging edges with a given set of unordered paths?